# How to convert 15 character salesforce id to 18 character salesforce id in LWC

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I want to conver 15 char salesforce id to 18 char salesforce id in LWC using JS.

i have tried below code but it does not give accurate id.

```
function convert15CharTo18CharId(id) {
  if (!id) throw new Error("id cannot be null or empty");
  if (id.length === 18) return id;
  if (id.length !== 15) throw new Error("Illegal argument length. 15 char string expected.");

  const triplet = [id.substring(0, 5), id.substring(5, 10), id.substring(10, 15)];
  const str = [];
  let suffix = "";

  for (const value of triplet) {
    str.length = 0;
    const reverse = value.split("").reverse();
    reverse.forEach(c => str.push(c.toUpperCase() === c ? "1" : "0"));
    suffix += binaryIdLookup[str.join("")];
  }
  return id + suffix;
}

const binaryIdLookup = {
  "00000": 'A', "00001": 'B', "00010": 'C', "00011": 'D', "00100": 'E',
  "00101": 'F', "00110": 'G', "00111": 'H', "01000": 'I', "01001": 'J',
  "01010": 'K', "01011": 'L', "01100": 'M', "01101": 'N', "01110": 'O',
  "01111": 'P', "10000": 'Q', "10001": 'R', "10010": 'S', "10011": 'T',
  "10100": 'U', "10101": 'V', "10110": 'W', "10111": 'X', "11000": 'Y',
  "11001": 'Z', "11010": '0', "11011": '1', "11100": '2', "11101": '3',
  "11110": '4', "11111": '5'
};
```

Comment: you can create an apex class that will cast the variable into Id and it will convert it to 18 characters like that: Id recordId = IdFromLWC;